# Windows PowerShell: Copy and Paste Explorer Column Settings between Folders

Tags: python, powershell

What is the way to Copy and Paste Explorer Column Settings between Folders in Windows 10 using PowerShell?

I have customized the explorer column headedrs manually by right clicking the column headedr and picking the headers I like.  I would like to copy  this customization and apply to other folders.

Powershell is preferred, but Python if fine as well.

Below is an example of customized column headers for a folder that I would like to copy to a different folder.  (header names are pointed by arrows for easy viewability.) Thanks.

[image: Example]

Comment: This should have something to do with Windows Registry and so called BAGS keys `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\`. Though, I am not sure how it works.

Comment: Thanks Igor.  I went  through the BAGS documentation but that is not useful for purpose of this question.  It is, however quite useful info for something else in the future.  Let's keep looking for the answer to this particular question.